# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. UseEffect problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still new to React and I stumble upon this problem. I've done prompt engineering to compose this code. My goal here is to pass data from a component called NumberOfKilos to the SMSForm which will receive the data passed and display them in the Summary Card React bootstrap component. I've spent countless hours to figure out how to solve it, but I did not come to one. If you would be so kind to help me. Big thanks.

Error message at browser console:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

SMSForm component (the child)

```
import NumberOfKilos from "../Components/NumberOfKilosCard";
import { Row, Col, Container, Form, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from "react";

function SMSForm() {
  const [kilosData, setKilosData] = useState({
    numKilosSale: 0,
    numKilosCredit: 0,
    totalKilos: 0,
    cashSales: 0,
    creditSales: 0,
    totalSales: 0,
  });

  // Function to update kilos data
  const handleKilosData = (data) => {
    setKilosData(data);
  };

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <NumberOfKilos handleKilosData={handleKilosData} />
        </Col>


        <Col md={3}>
          <Form>
            <Card>
              <Card.Header className='bg-dark text-light ' as="h4">
                Summary
              </Card.Header>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Number of Kilos (Sale):</Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  {kilosData.numKilosSale}
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Number of Kilos (Credit):</Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  {kilosData.numKilosCredit}
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Total Kilos:</Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  {kilosData.totalKilos}
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Cash Sales:</Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  {kilosData.cashSales}
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Credit Sales:</Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  {kilosData.creditSales}
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Total Sales:</Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  {kilosData.totalSales}
                </Col>
              </Row>


            </Card>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container >
  );
}

export default SMSForm;
```

NumberOfKilos component (the parent, the one who will passed the data)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FiTrash } from 'react-icons/fi';

function NumberOfKilos({ handleKilosData }) {
  const [numKilosRow, setNumKilosRow] = useState([
    { product: '', kilosSold: '', productSales: '', paymentStat: '' },
  ]);

  const handleAddNumKilosRow = () => {
    setNumKilosRow([...numKilosRow, { product: '', kilosSold: '', productSales: '', paymentStat: '' }]);
  };

  const handleDeleteNumKilosRow = (index) => {
    if (numKilosRow.length > 1) {
      const updatedKilosRows = [...numKilosRow];
      updatedKilosRows.splice(index, 1);
      setNumKilosRow(updatedKilosRows);
    }
  };

  const handleNumKilosChange = (value, index, field) => {
    const updatedKilosRows = [...numKilosRow];
    updatedKilosRows[index][field] = value;
    setNumKilosRow(updatedKilosRows);
  };

  const calculateKilosData = useCallback(() => {
    let saleKilosSum = 0;
    let creditKilosSum = 0;
    let cashSalesSum = 0;
    let creditSalesSum = 0;

    numKilosRow.forEach((row) => {
      if (row.paymentStat === 'Sale') {
        if (row.kilosSold) saleKilosSum += parseFloat(row.kilosSold);
        if (row.productSales) cashSalesSum += parseFloat(row.productSales);
      } else if (row.paymentStat === 'Credit') {
        if (row.kilosSold) creditKilosSum += parseFloat(row.kilosSold);
        if (row.productSales) creditSalesSum += parseFloat(row.productSales);
      }
    });

    const kilosDataObject = {
      numKilosRow,
      numKilosSale: saleKilosSum,
      numKilosCredit: creditKilosSum,
      cashSales: cashSalesSum,
      creditSales: creditSalesSum,
      totalKilos: saleKilosSum + creditKilosSum,
      totalSales: cashSalesSum + creditSalesSum,
    };

    handleKilosData(kilosDataObject);
  }, [numKilosRow, handleKilosData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateKilosData();
  }, [calculateKilosData]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form>
        <Row className='mb-3'>
          <Col>
            <Card style={{ height: '250px', overflow: 'auto' }}>
              <Card.Header as='h4' className='bg-dark text-light' style={{ position: 'sticky', top: '0', zIndex: '1' }}>
                Number of Kilos
              </Card.Header>

              <Row className='mx-3 mt-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Product</Form.Label>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Payment Status</Form.Label>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Kilos Sold</Form.Label>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>Product Sale</Form.Label>
                </Col>

                <Col xs={1}></Col>
              </Row>

              {numKilosRow.map((row, index) => (
                <Row className='mx-3' key={index}>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId={`productSelection${index}`}>
                      <Form.Select value={row.product} onChange={(e) => handleNumKilosChange(e.target.value, index, 'product')}>
                        <option>Select a product</option>
                        <option value='Fish'>Fish</option>
                        <option value='Squid'>Squid</option>
                        <option value='Octopus'>Octopus</option>
                        <option value='Cuttlefish'>Cuttlefish</option>
                        <option value='Cogita'>Cogita</option>
                      </Form.Select>
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Col>

                  <Col>
                    <Form.Select value={row.paymentStat} onChange={(e) => handleNumKilosChange(e.target.value, index, 'paymentStat')}>
                      <option>Select Status</option>
                      <option value='Sale'>Sale</option>
                      <option value='Credit'>Credit</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                  </Col>

                  <Col>
                    <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId={`kilosSold${index}`}>
                      <Form.Control type='number' placeholder='Enter kilos sold' value={row.kilosSold} onChange={(e) => handleNumKilosChange(e.target.value, index, 'kilosSold')} />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Col>

                  <Col>
                    <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId={`productSales${index}`}>
                      <Form.Control type='number' placeholder='Enter sale' value={row.productSales} onChange={(e) => handleNumKilosChange(e.target.value, index, 'productSales')} />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Col>

                  <Col xs={1}>
                    {numKilosRow.length > 1 && (
                      <Button variant='outline-danger' onClick={() => handleDeleteNumKilosRow(index)}>
                        <FiTrash />
                      </Button>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              ))}

              <Row className='mx-3 mb-3'>
                <Col>
                  <Button variant='primary' onClick={handleAddNumKilosRow}>
                    + Add Another Row
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default NumberOfKilos;
```

I've tried using callback as well as useRef which is suggested by the AI. But it did not help.

Comment: you should know about life-cycle of react hook specially for **useEffect**.  I think the main reason is usage of useEffect. your useEffect listen to changes of **calculateKilosData** function and call it inside. This logic call mutiple time and make a loop for you component updates.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to wrap handleKilosData inside `useCallback` as its in the array dependency of `calculateKilosData`.

Everytime i'm going to prop drill a function I wrap it in a `useCallback`, that way it prevents the function from losing reference inside the other component in case the top component re-renders.

```
const handleKilosData = useCallback((data) => {
  setKilosData(data);
}, [setKilosData])
```

When you call `handleKilosData(kilosDataObject)` you trigger a `setState` in your SMSForm component and it will re-render, when this happens, `handleKilosData` will lose it's reference and then `useCallback` will return a new function for `calculateKilosData` making `useEffect` trigger it once again because `calculateKilosData` has not the same reference as before, then the infinite loop happens.